# How can I Add a Team Project to a Team Project Collection on a Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-project

I don't recall the precise steps I took now to try to add a project to a Team Foundation Server, but it did not work.

What I intended to do was to add a project beneath CSReports (of which there are several related projects).

If I go to Source Control Explorer from Team Explorer in Visual Studio, I have both a CSReports and a RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil there, but the Connect to Team Foundation Server dialog shows no "RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil" below CSReports, nor even beneath Client Services; only CSReports appears beneath Client Services:

[image]

In Windows Explorer, it's even wackier: there's a CSReports" folder beneath \Workspaces, that has both another CSREports and a RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil on the same level:

[image]

So why is RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil "there" but not officially a Team Project in its own right? And how can I make it such? Do I need to start over? If so, how can I first get rid of the RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil where it does display? Is simply deleting the folder from Windows Explorer sufficient?

### UPDATE

I followed Tingting's steps, and it *seemed* to work, as I was able to subsequently check in the files from RoboRprtr without any clucking of tongues or wagging of fingers from the gnomes ensconced behind the digital curtain infesting the software, BUT, although RoboRprtr now ostensibly is part and parcel of the CSReports TeamProject, as can be seen in the Source Control Explorer in the Folders pane, RoboRprtr still does not appear in the list of projects beneath the "Client Services" Team Project Collection in the Connection dialog:

[image]

RoboRprtr should be a Team Project beneath "Client Services" on the same level as CSReports, not a sub-project of CSReports.

What the tarred-and-feathered Nation is going on here?

Comment: Sorry for the later response and cause I didn't receive any message alerts. And you have a folder named "CSReports " and a team project named "CSReports ", so it make me confused and sorry for the misunderstanding. And let me confirm your issue again: you want the RoboRprtr to be a team project under the same collection with "CSReports " team project and make the "RoboRprtr" project under "RoboRprtr" team project. If so, please refer to my reply and I have updated it.

Comment: I want RoboRprtr under CSReports. CSReports could have many projects/solutions under it, RoboRprtr being one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first picture you posted above, you haven't check in your changes. So please try the steps below to add the RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil project under CSReports team project.

1. At the collection level in Source Control Explorer, right-click and choose **Undo Pending changes**.
   [image]
2. Select RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil and click **Undo Changes**.
3. Now you can't see RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil project in Source Control Explorer.
4. In Windows Explorer, copy your RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil folder under CSReports folder.

[image]

5. In Source Control Explorer, right-click CSReports and choose **Add Items to Folder**.
6. Select RoboRprtrDateFilesGeneratorUtil folder and click **Finish**.

**Update:**

1. You need to create a team project named "RoboRprtr" first. You could create a team project from Team Explorer or from TFS web access page, please refer to [this document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project#from-team-explorer).
2. Then in Source Control Explorer, you will see the RoboRprtr team project. Connect to it and create a workspace mapping for it.
   [image]
3. In the "CSReports" team project, right click the "RoboRprtr" folder and choose **[Move...](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders#move-an-item-in-tfvc)**.
   [image]